# How can I mention there should return any child of parent class in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing, duck-typing

```
class Element:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Hello')
        return self


class Button(Element):
    pass


class TextBox(Element):
    pass


def some_func(element: Element) -> Element:
    return element()


some_func(Button)
some_func(TextBox)
```

Pycharm mentions "Expected type 'Element', got 'Type[Button]' instead ".
Is there any proper way to get type of the return as parent of all it's children?

Comment: which version of Python are you using ?

Comment: It should be `def some_func(element: Type[Element]) -> Element` or, even better (to preserve children classes), `some_func(element: t.Type[_T]) -> _T`, where `_T = t.TypeVar('_T', bound='Element')` and `import typing as t` was performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x: Element` means that `x` is an instance of the `Element` class.

Use `type[Element]` when you mean to pass a subclass of `Element`.

```py
def some_func(element: type[Element]) -> Element:
    return element()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Type[Element]. It seems works fine. But my friend told me that it means an instance of the class but not the class itself.
Seems like right answer is
`some_func(element: t.Type[_T]) -> _T`, where `_T = t.TypeVar('_T', bound='Element')` and `import typing as t` was performed.
But it's not very readable, so I prefer use Type[Element].
Thank you all! And especialy thanks to SUTerliakov.